# Generating a python nested dictionary by going thruogh a list of strings

Tags: python

I'm very new to python programming and trying to generate a dictionary dynamically to parse it for my script. For that, I will have to iterate through a list of string and use that as a dictionary to populate further values. In the below example, i have got an evaluated string as "ip_1" and this has to be a dictionary on which i need to populate some key,value pairs..

```
d = {}
vlan_start = 1001
no_of_vlans = 10
start = [1,2,3,4]


for i in range(vlan_start,vlan_start+no_of_vlans):
    d[i]={}
    for j in start:
        a = 'ip'+ '_' + str(j)  
        c = dict(a={})
        print(c)
```

the output that i got is : `{'a': {}}` instead the expected output is : `{'ip_1':{}}`

The Final output should be like this;

```
d = {1001:{'ip_1':{},'ip_2':{},'ip_3':{},'ip_4':{}},1002:{'ip_1':{},'ip_2':{},'ip_3':{},'ip_4':{}}
```

Comment: Why -1? What's wrong with the question. Explain A**h***!

Comment: what values want with in the brace?

Comment: As said in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict), "if keyword arguments are given, the keyword arguments and their values are added to the dictionary created from the positional argument". In other words, and as also shown in the examples in the documentation, the expected result of `dict(a={})` is `{'a': {}}`. Moral of the story: read the documentation of the things you are using, do not just expect things.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found a way to make it work!

A more concise solution making use of dict comprehension expressions is:

```py
vlan_start = 1001
no_of_vlans = 10

vlan_start = 1001
no_of_vlans = 10

ips =  {f"ip_{ip}": {} for ip in range(1,5)}
d = {
    vlan: ips for vlan in range(vlan_start, vlan_start + no_of_vlans)
}

assert d == {
    1001: {"ip_1": {}, "ip_2": {}, "ip_3": {}, "ip_4": {}},
    1002: {"ip_1": {}, "ip_2": {}, "ip_3": {}, "ip_4": {}},
    1003: {"ip_1": {}, "ip_2": {}, "ip_3": {}, "ip_4": {}},
    1004: {"ip_1": {}, "ip_2": {}, "ip_3": {}, "ip_4": {}},
    1005: {"ip_1": {}, "ip_2": {}, "ip_3": {}, "ip_4": {}},
    1006: {"ip_1": {}, "ip_2": {}, "ip_3": {}, "ip_4": {}},
    1007: {"ip_1": {}, "ip_2": {}, "ip_3": {}, "ip_4": {}},
    1008: {"ip_1": {}, "ip_2": {}, "ip_3": {}, "ip_4": {}},
    1009: {"ip_1": {}, "ip_2": {}, "ip_3": {}, "ip_4": {}},
    1010: {"ip_1": {}, "ip_2": {}, "ip_3": {}, "ip_4": {}},
}
```

You might want to check out a tutorial for dict comprehensions, such as https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension.